# Areca palm browning leaves

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, palm, dryness, areca-palm

This areca palm has seen better days - all the leaves keep drying out, even the one that came out 2 months ago is all brown now. I think it needs moisture. I mist it every few days and water once a week - literally putting in the shower and giving it a spray, then waiting 20-30 minutes to drain excess water before I put it back in the outer pot. We do have quite dry air and underfloor heating in the flat. It did survive last year with no problems though, it was all green and thriving. What can I do to get it healthy again?

[image]

Comment: Could you please mention your location, that would help in understanding environmental condition.

Comment: Not sure, but since it's a palm, have you ruled out frizzle top (manganese deficiency, or high pH, etc.)?